# Which foods are high in umami?

Tags: flavor

Which foods are high in [umami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umami) ("savoriness") and how can I cook them to maximize the umami taste?

Comment: Seems kind of open-ended to me... I'm not really sure how people are supposed to answer this.

Comment: you are probably right Aaronut, I saw it mentioned in another post and it got me wanting to know...

Comment: Too broad to be really answerable.

Comment: Shall I delete this?  There are no votes to close yet....

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to delete it with upvoted answers.  I guess it's okay, as a wiki; at least it introduces a concept that some people may not know [much] about.  'Course, the entire thread needs to be wikified, not just the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Umami comes from a very specific source: [Glutamates and glutamic acid](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Umami). MSG is a glutamate, so it is one of the best ways to add a bit of umami.

Meat, Kombu seaweed (used to make Dashi, and hence Dashi), mushrooms, onions, cheeses, soy and other beans, most high-protein foods.

[Here](http://www.dietandfitnesstoday.com/nutritioncontentsorted.php?nutid=515) is a quick list. Most are prepared foods, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Second ingredient in most bouillons, after salt, is MSG.

Answer (score 5):

Marmite / Vegemite contain [autolyzed yeast extract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeast_extract), which is a very high source of umami.  These spreads are therefore also great for bringing out savory flavours.

Answer (score 3):

- Anchovies
- Parmesan cheese
- Fish
- Meat

Answer (score 2):

The insides of Tomato's are high. Heston Blumanthal has a recipe for Tomatoe Ketchup that makes use of this.

Comment: Salting tomatoes really brings it out, too.

Answer (score -1):

Miso. Yummy, too.